# JPA - ArrayList relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, many-to-one

Hello I have this error message, I don't really know what to do.

"a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST"

I know there is something wrong about the entity relationship, but I tried a lot of things and it doesn't work.

Here are my two beans :

```
@Entity
public class Emoji implements Serializable  {

    private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public static void setSerialVersionUID(long aSerialVersionUID) {
        serialVersionUID = aSerialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Utilisateur createur;
    private String titre;
    private List<Message> conversations;...
```

...

```
@Entity
public class Message implements Serializable  {

    private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }


    public static void setSerialVersionUID(long aSerialVersionUID) {
        serialVersionUID = aSerialVersionUID;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String message;
    @ManyToOne
    private Utilisateur auteur;

    public Message() {
    } ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@OneToMany` annotation to your `conversations` field.

```
@Entity
public class Emoji implements Serializable  {

private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

public static void setSerialVersionUID(long aSerialVersionUID) {
    serialVersionUID = aSerialVersionUID;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
private Utilisateur createur;
private String titre;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Message> conversations;
}
```